# pass controller variable to my button on hover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to display my controller variable on hover of a button . I tried " :title => @variablename " but it doesnt seem to work

```
<%= link_to 'Refresh',
            '/dtr_refresh',
            id: 'refresh_dtr_link',
            class: 'btn btn-info',
            :title => @last_refreshed_time,
            remote: true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your instance variable (@last_refreshed_time) on your controller, here is an example

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @last_refreshed_time = Time.now
  end
end
```

Comment: no its not working , i have  "@last_refreshed_time = Time.now.to_s " it does not work on hover in my .html.erb file but on my .js file it works